# SQL: from event data to probability map

Tags: mysql, sql, pattern-recognition

I am interested to know whether the following can also be resolved with some (for me super advanced) SQL query.

I have a MySQL table with events (one row represents a device being turned on or off at a specific date & time). From this I'd like to extract patterns by calculating what the probability is for a specific device to be on or off at some specific time of the day (averaged out over all days in de DB).

With coding this is rather easy, but quite computational and I/O intensive. (I would just run through all rows and fill an array with a column for each minute of the day and then normalise.)

I am not super experienced in SQL, so I wonder whether I can do this smarter:

- is it possible to construct an SQL query that can do the same?
- Or at least the step in between (link an on and off event and - for that combination - fill a row with one minute for each day with a 0 or a 1).
- Or even better, extract the patterns :)

This is how far I got so far (not very):

```
SELECT `deviceID`
      , HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS hour
      , MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS minute
      , DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS`dayofweek`
      , newValue > 0 AS onoff
FROM `log_raw`
WHERE 1
```

Edit:
Thanks for the very quick replies. Rd_nielsen's answer already helps me one important step ahead.

For Degan:
My ideal output would be a row for each device (there are circa 30 devices) that has the probability for each minute of the day that it would be on (hence for the column representing 0:00, the value would be 0, while for column 6:30 the value would be 0.5, representing the likelihood that every 2 days the device is on)

Alternatively, a meaningful step in between, would be to derive a row for each on-off sequence where all columns between the time it was turned on and off would be ones, while all the others would be zeros. Would either of that work in SQL?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't recommend trying to do something so complicated with SQL. It is a database querying language and that is its specialty. You are much better off extracting the data into another language and then working with it from there.

Comment: When you say "some specific time of the day" do you mean that you are interested in just one time (which may vary for different queries), or do you mean that you are interested in every minute of the day (which other parts of your question imply)?  If it's the former, this can be done fairly straightforwardly in SQL--you will have to get each on-time and corresponding off-time of the device on a single row (possibly with a self-join) and then use WITHIN to determine whether the device was on during the time you're interested in.

Comment: I agree with the above. SQL is for the storage and retrieval of data. Everything else is for your application level code.

Comment: Can you describe your desired output as a table of data?  If you can, perhaps edit your question and add your desired output.  That would make it easy to determine how difficult this would be to accomplish in SQL.

Comment: See above for additional details